# How to place ID of each image over it

Tags: php, html, css

Hello I have a page which is retrieving images from database.

I need to place Image ID over images in its front means over image.

I tried alt but i don't think that will work.

How to do this ?

Here is my image code:

```
<a href="property.php?ImageID=<?php echo $row['ImageID'] ?>" >
          <img src="../../.../<?php echo $row['ImagePath'] ?>" width="380" height="270" alt="<?php echo $row['ImageName'] ?>" class="imagedropshadow" ></a>
```

Comment: You can use alt and title attributes

Comment: I think what you are looking for is a watermark on the image.

Comment: If you want a true watermark, you'd have to use an image manipulation library (possibly php-gd?). Otherwise, you'll have to overlay two HTML elements and have CSS position them respectively.

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily burn a watermark into the image for this. Perhaps what you're looking for is an [image caption that's absolutely positioned over the `img`](http://web.enavu.com/tutorials/making-image-overlay-caption-using-css/)?

Comment: @allejo: can you please give me some source for CSS one

Comment: @Rokhsar Matt's comment has a link to an example

Comment: Please specify why do you need IDs on image as from your question, it is not clear.

Comment: cause Image ID is retrieving from database its dynamic will it work with Matt;s example

Comment: The css solution won't stop people being able to download the original image to their computer, this will just appear to have a watermark when viewed on the website, but any user could very easily just download the image and when viewed on their computer, they will see no watermark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**CSS**

```
.property {
    width: 380px;
    height: 270px;
    box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 40px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.45);
    border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
    border-right: 2px solid #fff;
    margin: 5% auto 0 auto; 
    background-size: cover;
    border-radius: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.property-id {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.75);
    text-align: center;
    padding: 70px 0 70px 0;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease;
       -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease;
}

.property:hover .property-id {
    opacity: 1;
}

.property-id-text {
    font-family:Helvetica;
    font-weight:900;
    color:rgba(255,255,255,.85);
    font-size:96px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="property" style="background-image: url(../../.../<?php echo $row['ImagePath'] ?>)">
    <div class="property-id">
        <span class="property-id-text"><?php echo $row['ImageID'] ?></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Demo: [http://jsfiddle.net/asvuge2k](http://jsfiddle.net/asvuge2k/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="property.php?ImageID=<?php echo $row['ImageID'] ?>" >
      <img src="../../.../<?php echo $row['ImagePath'] ?>" width="380" height="270" title="<?php echo $row['ImageName'] ?>" class="imagedropshadow" ></a>
```

Comment: when you hover so the title will appear I want the Image ID to be placed over image

Answer (score -1):

```
<a href="property.php?ImageID=<?=$row['ImageID'] ?>">
        <span style="position: absolute; background-color: #ffffff"><?=$row['ImageID'] ?></span>
        <img src="../../.../<?php echo $row['ImagePath'] ?>" width="380" height="270" alt="<?=$row['ImageID'] ?>" class="imagedropshadow">
</a>
```